# Sub-pages not loading on Windows server

Tags: server, installation, windows

I just moved a site over to a Windows server, and my homepage loads fine, but sub pages are not loading. I just get an error message that the connection was reset. Adding index.php to the url doesn't do anything.

My control panel is also loading fine, it's just the sub-pages.

I don't really have any experience with Windows servers, so I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this. I'm using the standard craft web.config file. Is there a config setting I need to add?

Comment: What files did you move over? You might try clearing Craft's cache files (Settings -> Clear Caches) since Craft's caches rely on folder paths. If you're now on a different server/OS those paths will be different.

Comment: @RitterKnight  I moved over all files. Cleared caches and rebuilt image and search indexes. Same results.

Comment: Do you have access to the IIS error / event log? That should help determine why exactly the connection is being reset.

Comment: @RitterKnight I don't have access to the error log.

Comment: @artmem It's probably a 500 ISE error and the underlying error is probably in the IIS error logs / Windows event viewer. Maybe have your host look into the logs or at the least give you access to them?

Comment: Figured it out. Config was set to force https, but the new server didn't have an ssl certificate set up. Fixing that cleared up the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Config was set to force https, but the new server didn't have an ssl certificate set up. Fixing that cleared up the issue.